playsound module and pywinauto module cannot be used together
If you import playsound and pywinauto together, playsound does not work
This code works fine
import playsound
playsound.playsound('dir.mp3')

This code doesn't work
import playsound
import pywinauto
playsound.playsound('dir.mp3')

returns these errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Python\bb.py", line 3, in <module>
    playsound.playsound('dir.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 30, in winCommand
    '\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 0: invalid start byte  

The same applies if you delete the module.
import playsound
import pywinauto
del pywinauto
playsound.playsound('dir.mp3')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Python\bb.py", line 4, in <module>
    playsound.playsound('dir.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 30, in winCommand
    '\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 0: invalid start byte

